# Algorithme : Combinaison Of arrays PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I need to make a specific algorithm of possible combinations of arrays

For Info: I can't find a combination with elements from the same array =>  I can't find A12x because the 1 and 2 in the same array

```
example: ['A', 'B', 'C'], [1,2,3], ['x,y].

OutPut
A
A1
A2
A3
AX
AY
A1X
A1Y
A2X
A2Y
A3X
A3Y
B
B1
B2
B3
BX
BY
B1X
B1Y
.....
```

thank you in advance for your help
I tried with this block of code but I can't find the solution

```
<?php
// Enter your code here, enjoy!
$arrayGlobal = [['A', 'B'], ['1', '2', '3'], ['x', 'y']];
$result = [];
for($i=0; $i<count($arrayGlobal); $i++){
    $tab= $arrayGlobal[$i];
    for($j=0;$j<count($tab); $j++) {
        $result[] = $tab[$j];
        for($k=$i+1; $k<count($arrayGlobal); $k++) {
            $nextTab = $arrayGlobal[$k];
            for($y=0; $y<count($nextTab); $y++) {
                $result[] = $tab[$j].'-'.$nextTab[$y];
                
            }
        }
    }
        
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Why A12x? What about AB1x or A1xy, or even ABC123xy? What, exactly are you trying to create here?

Comment: this is the purpose of the exercise
I cannot have in my output a combination with elements of the same array